# Is there a jest way to mock Kotlin libraries?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

I know that with jest, you can mock the imports or libraries that other functions use, but can it be done in Kotlin?

I have a class that I am writing unit tests for, but one of the functions in that class interacts with AWS by calling ProfileCredentialsProvider() and DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().  I want to mock the calls to these com.amazonaws.auth libraries, but my ineffective googling has not worked out, and so the test actually tries to connect to AWS, instead of mocking the calls to the amazonaws libraries.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Or is this not a thing?

Comment: take a look at `mockk` library